# $%Sports Utility Vehicles$ SUV

Tags: cryptic-clues

<sup>Inspired by [XKCD 437](https://xkcd.com/437/) and the restricted title challenge. 
Special thanks to Deusovi for checking to see if my clues were valid.</sup>

---

1. Searcher for former myth in Puerto Rico. (8)
2. Cowboy wed redhead fisher. (8)
3. Thief hides in baro guesthouse. (5)
4. Request for repetition hidden in molten core. (6)
5. Sgt. Preston's home where gold was found. (5)
6. Ships give weapons to programmer LoveLace. (6)
7. Map is incomplete when all is said and done. (5)

Comment: BTW, slick trick @Mithrandir to shorten the title!

Comment: Unfortunately, the real xkcd title is too short for a question title. Does this still count as an entry in the challenge? Nevertheless, +1 for a neat puzzle, especially for getting it checked out first.

Comment: @noedne - my personal opinion - yes, it's OK. The titles were filtered to only include those with length > 15, but given Mithrandir's workaround (that doesn't include any padding/fake text), and Dragonrage's choice of xkcd being in the first 1000, it seems OK.

Comment: The filtering gave a way to winnow the possible xkcd titles down to a reasonable set, but the whole point of a restricted title challenge is, well, to use one of a restricted set of titles. This isn't one of them.

Comment: Cheers @Rubio, good to have that clarification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*The title indicates that each of the answers are in some way connected to sports utility vehicles.*

---

Searcher for former myth in Puerto Rico. (8)

> **EXPLORER** (former = *ex*, myth = *lore*, Puerto Rico = *PR*, hence exP*lore*R).
>  Title: [Ford Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_Explorer).

Cowboy wed redhead fisher. (8)

> **WRANGLER** (cowboy = wrangler, fisher = angler, *w*eds *r*edhead *angler*)
>  Title: [Jeep Wrangler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeep_Wrangler)

Thief hides in baro guesthouse. (5)

> **ROGUE** (ba*ro gue*sthouse)
>  Title: [Nissan Rogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nissan_Rogue)

Request for repetition hidden in molten core. (6)

> **ENCORE** (molt*en core*)
>  Title: [Buick Encore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opel_Mokka#Buick_Encore)

Sgt. Preston's home where gold was found. (5)

> **YUKON** (home of [a Gold Rush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klondike_Gold_Rush), and home of the titular character of [a TV series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergeant_Preston_of_the_Yukon_(TV_series)))
>  Title: [GMC Yukon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevrolet_Tahoe), cross-branded as a Chevy Tahoe

Ships give weapons to programmer LoveLace. (6)

> **ARMADA** (give weapons = ARM, programmer = [ADA Lovelace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_Lovelace))
>  Title: [Nissan Armada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nissan_Armada)

Map is incomplete when all is said and done. (5)

> **ATLAS** (Map = atlas, all is said and done = *at las*t)
>  Title: [Volkswagen Atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkswagen_Atlas)

---

*Many thanks to **[@noedne](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/48337/noedne)** for the first answer, and for how the title related to all seven answers.*

Comment: Ah, so that's how the title relates to all of them. I did not see that, apart from the 1st and 2nd, none of the others are sold in my country, so no name recognition!

Comment: @Phylyp I wouldn't have recognized them either, but this was my second guess for how the answers should look based on the title, after "each answer literally contains SUV."

Comment: nicely done. you solved those pretty quickly

Comment: Thank you @Dragonrage , and a nicely constructed puzzle as well. Although I totally didn't see the connection to the title until noedne had to almost spoon-feed it to me!